# how do i fix invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle, debugging, ora-01722

I am getting the error ORA-01722: invalid number when I run this code and I don't seem to know where the error is from:

> ORA-01722: invalid number

```
INSERT INTO P2720515_TP
  SELECT PRO_ID,
         THEATRE_ID,
         CLIENT_ID,
         TIME_ID,
         PURCHASE#,
         PAYMENTMETHOD,
         DELIVERYMETHOD,
         T_SUM
    FROM (SELECT P.PRO_ID,
                 T.THEATRE_ID,
                 C.CLIENT_ID,
                 TM.TIME_ID,
                 PURCHASE#,
                 PAYMENTMETHOD,
                 DELIVERYMETHOD,
                 SUM(TOTALAMOUNT) T_SUM
            FROM OPS$YYANG00.PERFORMANCE    PER,
                 P2720515_TM                TM,
                 P2720515_P                 P,
                 P2720515_T                 T,
                 P2720515_C                 C,
                 OPS$YYANG00.TICKETPURCHASE TP
           WHERE PER.P# = P.PRO_NO
             AND PER.THEATRE# = T.THEATRE_NO
             AND TP.CLIENT# = C.C_NO
             AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PER.PDATE) = TM.YEAR
             AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PER.PDATE) = TM.MONTH
           GROUP BY P.PRO_ID,
                    T.THEATRE_ID,
                    C.CLIENT_ID,
                    TM.TIME_ID,
                    PURCHASE#,
                    PAYMENTMETHOD,
                    DELIVERYMETHOD);
```

Comment: If you who has information about the table schema and the datatypes of the columns don't know where this error comes from, people who don't have this information will don't know, too. The fastest way to spot the invalid value within your insert command is to replace each value after each other by default values with correct datatype. As soon as the command will successfully be executed, the value that has last been replaced was incorrect.

Comment: Column names with a # without being double-quoted looks suspicious to me.

Comment: Are you sure that `TOTALAMOUNT` has a pure numeric values, ie. can you please tell us the data type of that column ?

Comment: TOTALAMOUNT datatype is Number @Barbaros

Answer (score 0):

when you trying to compare two different datatypes it usually gives that type of error (invalid number).
or you are using aggregate function with no aggregate values.

check all values that comes in columns which you are trying to aggregate or in comparison.

you can also use **cast function** to make it solve quickly.

Comment: Thank you Mari, any idea how the cast function could be used